# how to use for x with add attachment File Data vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

Helloooooooooooooooo all my friends

i use that code to add attach to my table  and it worked verry good

```html
       Dim rsEmployees As DAO.Recordset
   Set db = CurrentDb
   Set rsEmployees = db.OpenRecordset("FileAttach")
  Dim rsPictures As Object
  Dim x As Integer

   ' Activate edit mode.
   rsEmployees.AddNew
  
   ' Instantiate the child recordset.
   Set rsPictures = rsEmployees.Fields("AttachForms").Value
      rsPictures.AddNew


   ' Add a new attachment.

   rsPictures.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile "C:\Users\xmen5\Desktop\fl1.rar"
   rsPictures.Update
  
   ' Update the parent record
   rsEmployees.Update
Next
```

my proplem is when i use for x  with that code

```html
   Dim rsEmployees As DAO.Recordset
   Set db = CurrentDb
   Set rsEmployees = db.OpenRecordset("FileAttach")
  Dim rsPictures As Object
  Dim x As Integer

   ' Activate edit mode.
   rsEmployees.AddNew
  
   ' Instantiate the child recordset.
   Set rsPictures = rsEmployees.Fields("AttachForms").Value
    

For x = 1 To DCount("*", "[Attchment]")
  rsPictures.AddNew
   ' Add a new attachment.
   rsPictures.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile DLookup("[PathTxt]", "[Attchment]", "[id]=" & x & "")
   rsPictures.Update
  
   ' Update the parent record
   rsEmployees.Update
Next
```

it give me that error 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF7RJ.png)

i take path of attachment from table 
so how i use for x with that code

Answer (score 0):

Move the last line for update out of the loop:

```
    Next
' Update the parent record
rsEmployees.Update
```

Comment: how i make your answer is best answer ??

Comment: Great! Just mark it as answered - and click the up-triangle.